# Are there any duplication glitches present in the latest version of Minecraft for Xbox 360?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console, cheats

I have searched and watched many videos of duplication glitches, but every time I find one, its outdated and already fixed.

Is there a glitch that still works for the latest version of Minecraft for Xbox 360?

Comment: Hi Janjak, I've taken the liberty of changing the wording from 'best glitch', because that's a very subjective word and is likely to get this question closed. Ideally, you want *any* duplication glitch, not just the 'best' one.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Comment: Maybe you could specify the version, for future readers.  If someone posts an answer, and a new update comes out in the later months to patch it, the answer would be obsolete to the question.

Comment: #1-Im new on this site so I dont know all of the rules around here , no ofence but its true.                                                                                    #2-My xbox doesn't show me the version of the game so... yea, I dont know 

Comment: Im going to assume OP is keeping his game up to date. If a patch update invalidates an answer, ideally the poster will update their answer, or other answers with more up-to-date solutions will attract more votes. There is also an option for placing a bounty on answered questions, in order to entice users to bring an old anserr up to date. Asking for "the latest version" works better then asking for a particular version, as the question has the potential to be of more use to other users as time goes on. Your welcome to revise, to ask for a specific version, but as such I see no reason to.

Answer (score -2):

drop item, log out. Turn off console. Go back in. Done.

Answer (score -2):

Nether portal duplication
go to Nether and go back but at last secound when you get telepot place shulker block and immediately shut down your game
(Not save and quit) now go back again it shuld be duplicate
Copy your world youur progress might crash
Video link

Comment: This answer appears to be for the wrong edition of the game.